# How to get all projects in a SBT task?

Tags: plugins, sbt, projects

I'm writing a SBT task, which will get all projects of the whole project, then I can run some tasks against them.

The pseudo code is like:

```
val projects = someTaskToGetProjects.value
val updateReports = projects.map(p => (update in p).value)
```

But I can't find any task or setting to get the project list, how to do it?

Comment: I found method `projects.toList` will give me a list of projects in build file, but the `updateReports` line is still reports error `Illegal dynamic reference: p`

Answer (score 1):

I think [buildDependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/sxr/sbt/Keys.scala.html#sbt.Keys.buildDependencies) might suit your needs, otherwise [loadedBuild](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/sxr/sbt/Keys.scala.html#sbt.Keys.loadedBuild) has everything.

```
val projects = buildDependencies.value.classpath.keys
val updateReports = projects.map(p => (update in p).value)
```

Comment: Error: `Illegal dynamic reference: p`, the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30210418/342235