# How to get the dependencies of all sub-projects from a SBT project, in a SBT task?

Tags: scala, sbt, task

I'm write a SBT task, which can output the dependencies information, grouped by project (say a SBT project has multi projects)

I know there is a [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph/) plugin, but I can use it directly, because I want to generate a json file, but that plugin just output the dependency tree to console, without returning an data object, I can't easily get the data I want.

I found the `update` task returns a `UpdateReport` which contains a lot of information I want, but it only belong to the current project. In command line, if I want to know the information of all project, I can manually show all the projects by `projects` command, and view them one by one by `someproject/update`.

But how to do the same in a SBT task? I tried:

```
val reports = projects.toList.map(prj => (update in prj).value)
```

It reports:

```
[error] /Users/me/workspace/sbt-test/project/Build.scala:51: Illegal dynamic reference: prj
[error]     val reports = projects.toList.map(prj => (update in prj).value)
[error]                                                         ^
[error] one error found
```

How to fix it?

---

More code:

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object DemoBuild extends Build {

  lazy val allUpdate = taskKey[Unit]("show update reports of all projects")

  lazy val core = project
  lazy val web = project

  lazy val allUpdateDef = allUpdate := {
    val reports = projects.toList.map(prj => (update in prj).value)
    println(reports)
  }

  lazy val root = (project in file("."))
    .settings(
      allUpdateDef
    )

}
```

Comment: Can you share more code please?

Comment: @DaleWijnand question updated

Comment: `.value` is compile-time macro - so you should reference all your projects directly (`prj` should be known on compile-time), like `(update in prj1).value ++ (update in prj2).value ++ ...`  instead of just `prj`. However, there might be better options, so my answer isn't complete

Comment: I just found `val filter = ScopeFilter(inAnyProject, inAnyConfiguration); allUpdate := {println(update.all(filter).value)}` is very near to what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the document: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Tasks.html, I found the solution:

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object DemoBuild extends Build {

  lazy val groupByProject: Def.Initialize[Task[(String, UpdateReport)]] =
    Def.task {
      (thisProject.value.id, (update in thisProject).value)
    }

  lazy val filter = ScopeFilter(inAnyProject, inAnyConfiguration)

  updateByProject := {
    val subProjects = groupByProject.all(filter).value.map { case (  projectName, updateReport) =>
      ...
    }
  }
}
```